# Spring Security Login with static user dont work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a basic spring security login

My security config class is this:

```
package com.bookshelf2.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/anonymus*").anonymous() //role anonymus
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll() //resources
                .antMatchers("/addAuthors").hasRole("USER")
                //.antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")

                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws  Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("pippo").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1234")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

This is the login.html

```
<form class="row g-3 justify-content-center" th:action="@{perform_login}" method="post">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"  th:placeholder="#{name.user}" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  th:placeholder="#{name.pass}" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" th:text="#{add.user}"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <a href="http://localhost:8080/registration/" th:text="#{name.reg}">></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But when i try to login with username:pippo and password:1234 in my url appears ?error

like this : http://localhost:8080/demo/login?error

Using the auth.inMemoryAuthentication() user for login should work for authenticated this user with role "USER" so i dont know what is the problem.

Comment: i think next one [resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) will help you to solve it and also for your information the configuration that you provided is deprecated/removed from newest version of framework

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring will look for a parameter called `username` and `password`.
While you gave your form fields an ID (`id="username"` and `id="password"`), you didn't give them a `name` attribute.

To solve this, add a proper `name` attribute to your elements:

```html
<form class="row g-3 justify-content-center" th:action="@{perform_login}" method="post">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" th:placeholder="#{name.user}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" th:placeholder="#{name.pass}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" th:text="#{add.user}"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <a href="http://localhost:8080/registration/" th:text="#{name.reg}"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```